# PostgreSQL Finding all rows that have a time difference of over 5 seconds, for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which consists of data like below:

```
id       status       timestamp
1        REGISTERED   1000
2        REGISTERED   1030
2        COMPLETED    1031
1        PROCESSING   1035
3        REGISTERED   1040
3        COMPLETED    1041
1        COMPLETED    1048
4        REGISTERED   1049
5        REGISTERED   1050
5        PROCESSING   1056
6        REGISTERED   1060
6        PROCESSING   1062
6        COMPLETED    1080
```

I need to have a query that finds all rows in the REGISTERED state, that has the next row for that id occur >=5 timestamp units later, or is straight up missing.
For the above data, that would return these rows:

```
id       status       timestamp
1        REGISTERED   1000
4        REGISTERED   1049
5        REGISTERED   1050
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead`

```
select id, status, timestamp
from (
    select id, status, timestamp
       , lead(timestamp) over(partition by id order by timestamp) nxt
    from mytable
) t 
where status = 'REGISTERED' and (nxt is null or timestamp < nxt - 5)
```

Comment: I believe you meant "nxt - timestamp > 5",
but this is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Mathematically  "nxt - timestamp > 5" is exactly the same as "nxt - 5 > timestamp" and "timestamp < nxt - 5". But from the DB point of view the last two conditions are preferd, being SARGable.

Comment: I see, thanks for your response!